# No se puede visualizar 2 de mis gráficos al mismo tiempo en una pagina web | Chart.js

Tags: php, html5, chart.js

Al momento de insertar mis 2 graficas con el ID me muestra los 2 pero no al mismo tiempo, solo se ve 1 pero si recargo la pagina se ve el otro, ya intente de todo y no me muestra errores en la consola, ayudaaaa :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código con el que mando a traer los gráficos, al inicio marco que las 2 graficas se ejecuten pero solo lo hace una!!

```
    CargarDatosGraficosBar();
    CargarDatosGraficosBarHorizontal();
    let myChart;
    function CargarDatosGraficosBar(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'controlador_grafico.php',
            type:'POST'
        }).done(function(resp){
            if(resp.length>0){
                var titulo = [];
                var cantidad = [];
                var colores = [];
                var data = JSON.parse(resp);
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    titulo.push(data[i][1]);
                    cantidad.push(data[i][2]);
                    colores.push(colorRGB());
                }
                CrearGrafico(titulo,cantidad,colores,'bar','GRAFICOS EN BARRAS DE PRODUCTO','graficoBar');

            }
        })
    };
    function CargarDatosGraficosBarHorizontal(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'controlador_grafico.php',
            type:'POST'
        }).done(function(resp){
            if(resp.length>0){
                var titulo = [];
                var cantidad = [];
                var colores = [];
                var data = JSON.parse(resp);
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    titulo.push(data[i][1]);
                    cantidad.push(data[i][2]);
                    colores.push(colorRGB());
                }
                CrearGrafico(titulo, cantidad,colores,'line','GRAFICOS EN LINEA DE PRODUCTO','graficoLine');

            }
        })
    };
    function  CrearGrafico(titulo, cantidad,colores,tipo,emcabezado,id){
        const ctx = document.getElementById(id);
                if (myChart!=null) {
                    myChart.destroy();
                }
                myChart = new Chart(ctx,  {
                type: tipo,
                data: {
                    labels: titulo,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: emcabezado,
                        data: cantidad,
                        backgroundColor:colores,
                        borderColor:colores,
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    legend: { display: false },
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Aquí mando a llamar a las graficas en las cards que tengo asignadas y es donde me sale el error :(

```
       <div class="card-body">
         <canvas id="graficoBar" width="100%" height="70"></canvas>
      </div>
```

Comment: No hay forma de ayudar _a ciegas_: muestra un [repro] de lo que estás utilizando para mostrar los gráficos. No olvides que el código va _como texto, con formato_. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Listro bro, ya hice mas detallado mi problema :)

Comment: Según veo quieres generar dos gráficas, pero solo estas especificando un contenedor, o te genera una o la otra, has intentado generar funciones independientes **crearGrafico1** , **crearGrafico2** en diferentes contenedores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Rodrigo me hace un poco de ruido esto

```
if (myChart!=null) {
   myChart.destroy();
}
myChart =
```

Estas seteando una variable que entiendo que en chart.js es publica, el primer grafico la genera y el segundo al hacer el destroy te mata el grafico que te estaba mostrando previamente.
Intenta usar una variable que muera dentro de la funcion y sacar el destroy

```
       var grafico = new Chart(ctx,  {
            type: tipo,
            data: {
                labels: titulo,
                datasets: [{
                    label: emcabezado,
                    data: cantidad,
                    backgroundColor:colores,
                    borderColor:colores,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: { display: false },
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Si era eso, la verdad nunca se me paso por la cabeza eso, MUCHAS GRACIAS!